# Finding a table row using jquery closest method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m trying to get the row of a table using jquery closest method as below

```
function GetPackageSizeDescription() {
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
.....
//ajax call
data: { packageId: $(row).find('.packageId').val()}
}
```

but after jquery executes this line of code `var row = $(this).closest('tr');` the following line appears in the browser developer tools and I m unable to get the values of elements in that row.
`row = [prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: undefined]`

Any ideas?

The button element table cell looks like

```
 <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="GetPackageSizeDescription(); return false;">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
      </button>
  </td>
```

Comment: please share the html or a jsfiddle

Comment: What is `this` defined as within `GetPackageSizeDescription` ? Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: show the whole javascript related to the code above, or else we are just guessing what's really happening... $(this) is expected to be a child selector since closest will find the closest <tr> of every parent elements on the DOM

Comment: `$(this)` won't work inside the function unless you explicitly pass the parameter

Comment: better bind a click handler in the button, so $(this) can bind itself to it.

Comment: Many thanks @All. I understood the problem and fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send `this` through to the function as a parameter.

change to:

```
function GetPackageSizeDescription(element) {
var row = $(element).closest('tr');
```

and when you call `GetPackageSizeDescription` do:

```
GetPackageSizeDescription(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can refactor your code to this...

HTML

```
<td><button id="getpackagesize-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
      </button>
</td>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#getpackagesize-btn').on('click', function() {

   var row = $(this).closest('tr');
   ...

   //ajax call
   data: { packageId: $(row).find('.packageId').val()}

   return false;
});
```